# deleting word by word at linux command prompt

Tags: linux

I want to delete word by word when at linux prompt.

```
For ex :
[user@system]$ python myscript.py -s some_test_case -u some_other_flag
```

I'm running this command whole day with varying text after "-u", it's tedious to delete the text by using a backspace everytime. I searched for the linux commands as per my requirement but I find commands to either cancel out the whole command or replace last 2 characters or some other command irrelevant to me. Is there a command for this at all?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix/Linux usage, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: See my answer below? Are you happy deleting one word at a time?

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> will delete the last word backwards from the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You can try googling `shell delete word` or

try `Ctrl + W`